# Looking for Android number picker (10-key style)

Tags: android, dialog, picker

I am looking around for a number picker in a 10-key style, ideally as a dialog... but called as an activity is fine too.  I want to offer the user an interface that is a little more directed toward entering $ for an invoice amount field.  I have seen adjustments to the date and time pickers but they looked awkward for this application.  I have also seem someone call the built-in calculator, which would be fine, but I don't know how they were capturing a returned value (if they were).  Any ideas?  Yes, I can fall back to a regular edit field and the standard android keyboard... I was just hoping for something a little more slick. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried setting the attribute `android:numeric` on the `TextView`?

- [`TextView` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3anumeric)

Comment: Aaargh!!  I hate it when my new is showing!  Thanks, Dave.  That is definitely a step better than the keyboard in qwerty-mode.  I'll wait a little while to see if anyone has seen something really slick and if not, i'll go with 'numeric'.  Thanks again!

Comment: I just realized that the android:numeric looks very different between sdk versions 8 and 9.  What I wanted all along is a 10-key style number selector widget instead of the small-button keyboard approach.  This is implemented in sdk 9 and I had been testing all along with sdk 7.  Thanks again to dave.c!